# Task[List[List[A]]] to Task[A] if list has elements

Tags: scala, monix

I have a method which returns Task[List[List[A]]] and I need to transform to Task[A] if the list is greater than 0

```
def method():Task[List[List[A]]] = {}

val d:Task[List[A]] = method().map(_.flatten)
```

How to get Task[A] is a list of A if the inner method has more than 0 elements

I am able to convert to Task[List[A]] as you can see above

Comment: You mean you want to take the first element from the list or transform `Task[List[A]]` to `List[Task[A]]`?

Comment: yes I want the first element Task[List[A]] if List[A] >0

Comment: Final output should be Task[A]

Comment: You know... for example... getting an `Int` from a `List[Int]` you will need some operation to combine all elements or select one element or something similar.

Comment: What should happen if all lists are empty? Also you said you wanted the first element, but the first of all lists or ten first of the first list? It would be good if you could put some example inputs with expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're flattening the `List[List[A]]` into a `List[A]` in the intuitive way, all wrapped in a `Task`. If you provide the method to go from a `List[A]` to an `A` (edit: see below), then you can call it from a map on the task as follows.

```scala
def method():Task[List[List[A]]] = {}

def listToItem(list: List[A]): A = ???

def d: Task[A] = method().map(_.flatten).map(listToItem(_))
```

You say that you want `listToItem` to take the first element of the list. Unfortunately, such a function wouldn't know what to do if the list were empty. You could use `list.head`, which will throw an exception if the list is empty, or you could use `list.headOption`, which will return an `Option[T]` rather than `T`.

Comment: did you realise you just called `listOfA.map(listToA(_))`. `method().map(_.flatten.map(listToItem(_)))` should be changed to `method().map(_.flatten).map(listToItem(_))`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh sure, but to fit with OP's code, it starts from `Task[List[List[A]]`, and I think this is the clearest way to show what's changed.

Comment: method().map(_.flatten.map(a=>a)) why this is wrong

Comment: @gandaliter your code will not compile. Types are wrong.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Ah, sorry, misunderstood. Edited - thanks

Comment: @Sumeet `map` just allows you to operate inside the monad (`List` in this case, but similarly for `Task` elsewhere). Calling `list.map(a => a)` gives you another `List`, the same as the original one.